# Get admin credentials for a .aspx website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have this website that was built using .aspx and SQL Server database. Now I somehow lost it's password. I didn't build the website and I am not familiar with Microsoft's technologies as far as web software is concerned and I can't get hold of the developer who built it.

What I know is that the credentials are stored in the database somewhere and all the application does is cross check and validates the entered values.

I have the database as a text file but I can't understand the syntax.

I have tried to decipher the file but no luck yet. The line below caught my eye

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblAdminUser] ON

INSERT [dbo].[tblAdminUser] ([inAdminUserId], [inDeptId], [inUserTypeId], [stUserName], [stPassword], [stFirstName], [stLastName], [stEmail], [stDesignation], [stContactNo], [flgIsActive], [flgIsDeleted])   
VALUES (1, NULL, 1, N'admin', 0x61646D696E, N'Njoroge', N'Regeru', N'info@regeru.com', N'CEO', NULL, 1, 0)
```

Could someone help me in getting the username and password? I am not sure if the credentials are in the above line of code.

Comment: Please take note that posting whole database script including stored procedure is not recommend here.

Comment: The username is easy, that should be admin according to the scripot you posted, but the password should be, if the developer has any sense, encrypted or hashed, and that seems to be the case. You need to look in the code to figure out if you can get the password from the data in the database. If it's hashed, you're out of luck.

Comment: yeah i can tell the username but the below code has the password 0x61646D696E

Comment: Try to find how do the password is encrypted in your program. Try using a sample password like "Test" and see what is the encrypted value (if u debug you can find the encrypted value). Once you get the encrypted value, u update the old password with the new password. Now you can login using the updated password next time.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it your password is hashed. Your username is in there. I would suggest seeing if there is an option within the site for password reset or recovery. If that is not an option you could create another user or keep trying to contact the developer.

The password is hashed so it is not decipherable to the human eye. If it was in plain text it wouldn't be secure and therefore would make it pointless having the password in the first place